# Can I add JComboBox to an specific index in Array of Objects?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I need to add JComboBox to an index in array of Objects, as this array contain also other Objects like, String, int etc., to add all of them to a row in JTable.

Hint: I tried to solve it using this code"TableListSuppliers.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combSupplierProducts))" and it did not work, so can I try to solve it as I mention in my question.

```java
public void addRowToJTable()
    {
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) TableListSuppliers.getModel();
        Object [] data = new Object[6];
        Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
        ArrayList <Supplier> suppliers = new ArrayList <> ();


        suppliers = supplier.ListSuppliers();        

        tableModel.setRowCount(0);

        int suppliersSize = suppliers.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < suppliersSize; i++)
        {
            Product product = new Product();
            ArrayList <Product> products = new ArrayList <> ();

            products = product.listProducts();

            int productsSize = products.size();
            String [] supplierProducts = new String[productsSize];

            for(int j = 0; j < productsSize; j++)
            {
                if(suppliers.get(i).getSupplierName().equals(products.get(j).getProductSupplierName()))
                {
                    supplierProducts[j] = products.get(j).getProductName();
                }

            }

            JComboBox combSupplierProducts = new JComboBox (supplierProducts);

            data[5] = i + 1;
            data[4] = suppliers.get(i).getSupplierNumber();
            data[3] = suppliers.get(i).getSupplierName();
            //TableListSuppliers.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combSupplierProducts));
            //data[2] = column;
            data[1] = suppliers.get(i).getSupplierPhone();
            data[0] = suppliers.get(i).getSupplierAddres();

            tableModel.addRow(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to set a `JComboBox` as the editor for a column in a `JTable`?

Comment: Yes , but I try to use this code TableListSuppliers.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combSupplierProducts)) it didn't work as I add full row every iteration so can I add this ComboBox to the object array data

Comment: Did you get an `Exception`? If yes, then [edit] your question and add the exception message and the entire stack trace. Can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: No exceptions, it works will, the whole problem is to add JComboBox to the table directly or by assign the JComboBox to the data array, what is the technique to do that according to this piece of code

Comment: Forgive me, but it is still unclear to me what you are trying to do. **PLEASE** post a [mcve]. Then I can copy your code and run it and see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I will explain to you in more details

Comment: Thanks very much for your interest, my problem has been solved, I'm glad to meet you.

Comment: Perhaps you can share how you solved the problem so that others who come across this problem will know how to solve it.

Comment: ok, I set JTable Editable to false so it did not work because this reason

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question. how can I set JTextArea Alignment to right ?

Comment: _how can I set JTextArea Alignment to right_ This is a new question. It is not related to this question that you posted. You should post a new question. Have you? And remember to post a [mcve]. Hint: [ComponentOrientation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/ComponentOrientation.html).

Comment: I will do that.